# XCOPY not overwriting files

Tags: xcopy

Hello I use the following code inside a **BAT** file to move files but the xcopy **fails** to overwrite the files:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\AGL\Desktop\DATA\MT4BACK"  "C:\Users\AGL\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\2010C2441A263399B34F537D91A53AC9" /e /y /r
```

Please let me know what migth be the problem

Answer (score 0):

For more info run `xcopy help` in `CMD`, this will explain you all possibilities.
You can try to use different options then.

**EDIT**

You can add `PAUSE` at the end of bat file, so you can read xcopy output info

Comment: thank you - the /e  parameter shpoudl overwrite everytnhing?

Comment: /r should do this, would say, add pause to bat file and see what is going on there, maybe file is in use

Comment: maybe test some basic files on c:\temp